# Need help in swagger UI genration on my go program

Tags: go, swagger-ui

I am new to Golang and APIs.

We have service file which contains

```
getBookHistory(context Context, book string)([]*model.lookuprecord, error){
//some code
}
```

in my rest.go (handler)

```
// GetBookHistoryLookup godoc
// @Summary Shows historic detailed  Info.
// @Description get history details from the  table in the database.
// @Param book path string true "book"
// @Produce  json
// @Success 200 {object} iModel.LookupRecord
// @Router /history/{book} [get] 
func(h handler) GetBookHistoryLookup(c echo.Context){
//some code
}
```

I am using github.com/swaggo/swag/cmd/swag lib.

It produces a swaggerUI but the response is null for this get service.
I can see the return type is array and need to change to the line

```
// @Success 200 {object} iModel.LookupRecord
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you share `*model.lookuprecord` struct.

Comment: @OmkeshSajjanwar -
`type LookupRecord struct {
 ID         int64     `json:"id" db:"id" goqu:"skipinsert"`
 Iat        time.Time `json:"iat" db:"iat"`
 Identifier string    `json:"identifier,omitempty" db:"identifier"`
 Record     *Result `json:"record,omitempty" db:"result_set"`
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// @Success 200 {object} iModel.LookupRecord
```

to be replaced with

```
// @Success 200 {object} []iModel.LookupRecord
```